# aurelia i18n updateTranslations not refreshing RC

Tags: aurelia

Problem is only when using

```
${'message' | t }
```

When i use format

```
t="message"
```

it shows blank (nothing) but responds to language change and then shows.

```
s.subscribe('i18n:locale:changed', payload => {
      this.i18n.updateTranslations(this.element);
});
```

gets hit when changeing the language but nothing is refreshed.

Greetings

Comment: Check if using latest version of `aurelia-i18n` and use `${'message' & t }` syntax

Comment: thanks Valichek, i'm using 1.0.0-rc.1.0.0. I can't upgrade because i don't want to upgrade all aurelia because i got into lot's ot other troubles/errors then (aurelia-breeze related). which i couldn't solve. I tried your suggestion (change | to &) but that didn't work

Comment: not sure about `1.0.0-rc.1.0.0`, another option for you is to try `${'message' | t & signal:'aurelia-translation-signal'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that ValueConverters cannot be signaled from outside to indicate a re-evaluation.

Exactly for this case the TBindingBehavior was introduced as @valichek mentioned. If that isn't working I'd ask you to create an issue in the official repo, including a small sample depicting the problem.

Comment: Changing the | for & did work after all, even in the RC. Thanks